# Expression With and Union All to EF Core

Tags: c#, sql, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to convert this SQL query to EF Core code.
I don't want to use LINQ, any possibility?

```
with cat (id, id_parent, name) as
(
    select id, id_parent, name
    from categories
    where categories.id = 9

    union all

    select e.id, e.id_parent, e.name
    from dbo.categories e
    inner join brands b on b.id_parent = e.id
); 
select * from cat;
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Why are you using EF if you don't want to use LINQ? LINQ to Entities is how you do queries in EF, unless you want to write your own Entity SQL, which should only be done if you can't achieve what you want using LINQ. Do you actually mean that you don't want to use LINQ to Objects?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use Linq method syntax? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build a recursive query. Note that if you cause EF Core to load the records you are interested in, the framework will link navigations together to build the hierarchy for you.

Comment: There are multiple methods that you can use: ``Union``, ``Concat``

Answer (score 2):

If I get your question correctly this would work for you:

```cs
 var result = await _dbContext.Categories
                .Where(x => x.Id == 9)
                .Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Parent = x.IdParent, Name = x.Name})
                .Concat(
                    _dbContext.Categories.Join(_dbContext.Brands, cat=> cat.Id, brand=> brand.IdParent, (cat,brand)=>cat)
                    .Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Parent = x.IdParent, Name = x.Name }))
                .ToListAsync();
```